# SQL statements for finding percentage on multiple values

Tags: mysql

I have three tables that hold items like:

```
Products:
  ID   NAME     CATEGORY   STOCK
   1   Bolts      3          1
   2   Daisies    4          1
   3   Milk       5          2
   4   Washers    3          3
   5   Roses      4          1

Categories:
  ID  DESCRIPTION
   3  Hardware
   4  Plants
   5  Food

Stocks:
  ID DESCRIPTION
   1 In Stock
   2 Out of Stock
   3 Ordered
```

I've been banging my head to get an SQL statement that will return a percentage of my items that are in stock based on their category, but I just can't make it work.

I'm looking for a statement that will return something like:

```
CATEGORY    PERCENTAGE   // comments
Hardware      50         // Bolts in stock but washers are ordered
Plants       100         // all plants in stock
Food           0         // milk is out of stock
```

Any ideas...?

Comment: So for this purpose, ordered means out of stock and ordered?  What if it is in stock and ordered?  Most of the time, you wouldn't want to wait until its out of stock to order it.

Comment: Well, you're correct.  But that's just a business rule.  I'm actually interested in the sql statement.  The example is stripped down to it's basics so it's easy to digest. :)

Comment: I was just making sure, because that changes the sql statement on how to treat the 3 in the stock column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select DESCRIPTION, sum(STOCK = 1) / count(*) as PERCENTAGE
from Products p
join Categories c on c.id = p.CATEGORY
group by DESCRIPTION
```

This works because `STOCK = 1` is a boolean, which is `1` if true and `0` if false, so `SUM(STOCK = 1)` counts how many times `STOCK = 1` is true!

Comment: What I missed in my failed tries was the ability of sum() to include a statement like "stock = 1".  Thanks, that works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see the use of this statement, but it would be

```
SELECT c.DESCRIPTION, count(p.STOCK = 1) / count(*) * 100
FROM CATEGORY c
JOIN PRODUCT p ON p.CATEGORY = c.ID
GROUP BY c.ID, c.DESCRIPTION
```

Should do it.